# How do I use scanf to name a file?

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm trying to make a sort of note pad for the command prompt with C++. I want someone to be able to put in the name they want for the file and what they want in the file. How would I do that? This is what I have:

```
printf("What do you want to call it?\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &filename);

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("%s", filename);
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
```

If you want, you can edit this or just make it from scratch.
Also, please help me let them type what they want in it.

Comment: It would be simpler if you used c++. I mean std::cin instead of scanf_s and std::cout instead of printf

Comment: Not `myfile.open("%s", filename);`, just `myfile.open(filename);`.

Comment: @RSahu that didn't work. It says it should be const char but comes out with an error still. Also, I get this " 3 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::open [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int)
            object type is: std::ofstream c:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Burd\WordPad\WordPad\WordPad.cpp 27 9 WordPad
"

Comment: @TyceG, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting bits and pieces and responding to the bits and pieces is not productive.

Comment: You should also use `std::string` rather than character arrays.  The `scanf` family doesn't read into `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code I think you are looking for:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
  std::string filename;
  std::cout << "Enter filename to create: ";
  std::cin >> filename;
  std::ofstream my_file(filename.c_str());
  if (my_file)
  {
    my_file << "Sample text\n";
    my_file.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```